# Number of poles used for calculating synchronous speed

Tags: motor, synchronous, synchronous-motor

I am a bit confused in the formula used to determine the synchronous speed \$N_S\$. Following is the formula used to determine the speed:

\$N_S = \frac{120f}{p}\$

Now for a 6 pole motor there are some sites where 6 is first divided by 2 and then the answer got is used for \$p\$ and there are some sites that use 6 for \$p\$. Can somebody clear this confusion? Also do the number of poles affect the phase difference? Like for 6 pole three-phase motor the phase difference would be 120 irrespective of the number of poles or would it be 60?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

More than one winding and more than one phase contributes to the formation of one pole. In a three phase motor, the magnetic effects of each of the three phase windings are added together to form each pole. Within a phase, several distributed windings may be part of a phase. In single-phase motors, a main winding and an auxiliary winding or a shaded-pole winding forms each pole.

The formula in which p is the number of poles, \$N_S = \frac{120f}{p}\$, is the formula that is most often used. In the few texts or articles where p is the number of pole-pairs, the formula \$N_S = \frac{60f}{p}\$ is used. Of the dozen or so motor texts that I have, I believe that only one does calculations with pole-pairs. In the 60 years that I have been studying or working with AC motors, I have very rarely encountered any calculations using pole-pairs.

Answer (score 1):

> *Can somebody clear this confusion?*

Poles effectively come in pairs (pole-pairs). You need to consider that a machine with 6 numerical poles is in fact a 3 pole-pair machine. Some sites will use the pole-pair count and some (fewer) will count all poles and then divide by 2.

> *do the number of poles affect the phase difference?*

No, the phase difference between the three supply phases is always nominally 120°. However, the physical angle rotated by the rotor gets smaller per cycle as the number of pole-pairs increases.

Comment: but the book i have been reading also used 6 for \$p\$.

Comment: Maybe you need to find a book that clearly states what p is i.e. numerical poles or pole pairs.

Comment: Check Hughes Electrical technolgy